# Apply CSS style to asp content

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I can apply a CSS style to an html link using

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a href="/members/Default.aspx" id="loginCss">Login</a>
```

Is it possible to apply the same CSS style id loginCSS to the following control?

```
    <div class="buttonCSS">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Default.aspx" >Login as Admin</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
```

I've tried the following

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="loginCss" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl="~/Members/Default.aspx" >Login as Member</asp:HyperLink>
```

which gives error `'loginCSS' is not a valid identifier.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, I'm guessing you have a style based on control names:

```
#loginCss{

   //Your styles here

}
```

If you change it to be based on class name:

```
.NewLoginCss{

   //Your styles here

 }
```

You can reference it in multiple places using the .NET `CssClass` and HTML `class` attributes:

```
<a href="/members/Default.aspx" id="loginCss" class="NewLoginCss">Login</a>

<asp:HyperLink ID="loginCss" runat="server" 
     NavigateUrl="~/Members/Default.aspx" 
     CssClass="NewLoginCss">Login as Member</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to avoid using IDs when dealing with .NET web controls as the IDs end up looking something like: `ct100_blahblah_controlName_blahblah`

So just use the CssClass attribute in the Hyperlink Control:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="hyp1" CssClass="className" />
```

And your CSS would be:

```
.className { color: FFF; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe ID's are pretty reserved in the older versions of .NET which is why many backend devs prefer their front-end buddies to use css classes instead.

You can look up how to apply those on your elements, but I believe its `CssClass="classname"`

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="" CssClass="loginCss" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl="~/Members/Default.aspx" >Login as Member</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you add "runat='server'"
all ids will be prepended with ContentPlaceHolder_

so if ur id before server side was "bla"
it will be "ContentPlaceHolder_bla"
and thats the name u should use for selectors on client side.
from server side the elements will still be available by old name.

Comment: This is not a good approach specially in case of Css as one could have nested content place holder and id's get quite complex in that case.

Comment: agreed. but this is the standard procedure to grab the ID from client side if the control runs on server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same ID of two ASP.Net controls. There are other ways to achieve your goal. A better approach is to use CssClass attribute.